# Get members of custom class to read their values

Tags: c#, class, class-members

Let say I have class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Field1 = 1234567890;
    public string Method1() { return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"; }
}
```

... class instance and list:

```
TestClass TC = new TestClass();    
List<object> TCValues = new List<object>();
```

... and populate the list with values in loop:

```
        foreach (var v in TC.GetType().GetProperties()) // or .GetFields()
        {
            TCValues.Add(v.GetValue(TC, null));                
        }
```

... problem is that in my particular case I need to get list of all class members first, then filter them to properties and fields (ignoring methods of course) and then read their values as I did in first example:

```
        foreach (var v in TC.GetType().GetMembers())
        {
            if (v.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property || v.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                TCValues.Add(v.?????????); // Can't get values !
            }
        }
```

... I understand that `GetMembers()` returns class `MemberInfo` which unlike `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo` doesn't contain method `GetValue()`. Is there any way to read values from filtered property and field members inside the loop iterating through `MemberInfo` collection ?

Answer (score 3):

In your foreach-Loop try

```
foreach (var v in TC.GetType().GetMembers())
{
    if (v is PropertyInfo)
    {
       var value = ((PropertyInfo)v).GetValue(TC, null);
       TCValues.Add(value);
    }
    else if (v is FieldInfo)
    {
       var value = ((FieldInfo) v).GetValue(TC);
       TCValues.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. So if I understand properly, 'MemberInfo' is base for 'PropertyInfo' and 'FieldInfo'. I can't see 'GetValue()' because 'MemberInfo' doesn't point into it, so I need to cast it as f.e. 'FieldInfo' to see 'GetValue()' method.

Comment: Yes, MemberInfo is base class of PropertyInfo and FieldInfo. But it does not expose GetValue() because the implementations and the signature is different for properties and fields.

Answer (score 0):

TC.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(TC);

Answer (score -1):

You have to cast the members to the correct type:

```
foreach (var v in TC.GetType().GetMembers())
{
    if (v.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        TCValues.Add(((System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)v).GetValue(TC,null)); 
    }
    else if (v.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field)
    {
        TCValues.Add(((System.Reflection.FieldInfo)v).GetValue(TC));
    }
}
```